# Error: Member "send" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup

Tags: addresses, send

I am trying to compile the following smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1; 
contract Governmental{
   uint constant TWELVE_HOURS = 12;
   
   function lendGovernmentMoney ( address buddy ) public  returns ( bool ) {
      address owner;
      uint[] memory creditorAddresses;
      uint lastTimeOfNewCredit =0;
      uint amount = msg. value ;
      uint creditorAmounts = 0;
      uint profitFromCrash = 0;
      uint round = 0;
      uint lastCreditorPayedOut = 0;
       
      // check the condition to end the game
      if ( lastTimeOfNewCredit + TWELVE_HOURS > block . timestamp ) {
         msg.sender.send ( amount );
         // Sends jacpot to the last creditor
         creditorAddresses[creditorAddresses.length - 1].send ( profitFromCrash );
         owner.send (this.balance);
         // Reset contract state
         lastCreditorPayedOut = 0;
         lastTimeOfNewCredit = block . timestamp ;
         profitFromCrash = 0;
         creditorAddresses = new address [](0);
         creditorAmounts = new uint [](0);
         round += 1;
         return false ;
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> prg17.sol:20:10: Error: Member "send" not found or not visible after
> argument-dependent lookup in uint256.
> creditorAddresses[creditorAddresses.length - 1].send ( profitFromCrash );
> ^--------------------------------------------------^

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`creditorAddresses` is declared as a uint array.

```
uint[] memory creditorAddresses;
```

Prabably you meant to declare it as an address array

```
address payable[] memory creditorAddresses;
```

Also this code `creditorAddresses[creditorAddresses.length - 1]` won't work when the array is empty. Which is the case if the memory array isn't initialized like the snippet.

Comment: Hi, my friend @Ismael your solution gives the arror:  Error: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"., when I am using payable, I get the error: Error: Expected ';' but got 'payable', Somebody please guide me. Zulfi.

Comment: @zak100 Sorry, my mistake. It should have been `address payable[] memory creditorAddresses`.

Comment: Hi, my firend @Ismael, I am now getting 2 errors:   (1) Error: Type address[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable[] memory.
         creditorAddresses = new address [](0); and  (2)Error: Type uint256[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
         creditorAmounts = new uint [](0);........Please guide me. Zulfi.

Comment: @zak100 You can fix by allocating `address payable` instead. Something like `creditorAddresses = new address payable[](0)`